# Встраивание одного html документа в другой

Tags: html

iframe использовать нельзя. Нужно вывести в определенное место страницы с помощью ajax, но при этом возникает конфликт имен css классов, имен js функций и переменных.  Неужели все придётся переименовывать?

Comment: Вы знаете о Web Components? Еще не поддерживается во многих браузеров, но есть библиотеки для этого, например [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org).

Answer (score 1):

Переименовать придется: в будущем другие проблемы могут возникнуть.